# Problem with boot from USB installing Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, boot-failure

I'm trying to install ubuntu 12.04 using USB. After downloading the ISO file, I used pendrive to make bootable USB drive but after restarting my computer, I encounter this error:

Unknown keyword in configuration file: ...
vesamenu.c32 : not a COM32R image
boot:

I need your help as soon as possible.

Comment: 1. Make sure the iso is not corrupt. 2. Give more details on how you created the bootable USB drive.

Answer (score 0):

You may try making your bootable USB flash drive using [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/).